# Deploying Laravel backend and multiple vue frontend apps on the same server

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, nginx

I have a Laravel and several Vue apps. I'm trying to deploy them on Digital Ocean using docker and nginx.

I've never deployed apps before, so I poorly understand the process. I've already deployed Laravel backend and I am thinking of deploying my vue apps in separate docker containers, but I dont actually understand how should I configure my nginx server.

I've found out I could build my frontend app into the Laravel's public folder, but this approach works with a single Vue app, while I have several.

I'd use some help on how to manage this. Thanks in advance!

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`(without vue yet) :

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: shop_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/shop/backend
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
    networks:
      - shop
  laravel:
    container_name: shop_laravel
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www/shop/backend'
    networks:
      - shop
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
      - redis
  pgsql:
    container_name: shop_postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: 'postgres:14'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      PGPASSWORD: 'shop'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'shop'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'shop'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'shop'
    volumes:
      - 'shop-pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    networks:
      - shop
  redis:
    container_name: shop_redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'shop-redis:/data'
    networks:
      - shop
networks:
  shop:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  shop-pgsql:
    driver: local
  shop-redis:
    driver: local
```

And nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name shop.laravel;
    root /var/www/shop/backend/public;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Comment: You currently have an nginx configuration to serve `shop.laravel` now you'd need more nginx configurations for each of your front-end sites. Since they are vue sites they will be served as static content (so no need for a fastcgi bit)

Comment: And they will also run on port 8080? How should i avoid url conflicts then?

Comment: Usually resolultion happens based on the URL. For example you can have `backend.example.com` for your laravel app and `app1.example.com`, `app2.example.com` for your frontend apps and nginx can use the corresponding configuration based on the server name. This requires you to set up DNS entries for each app to all point to the same endpoint (which ultimately forwards traffic to your nginx container)